# setContentView error on Google Maps V2

Tags: android, maps

I'm try to add a map inside my android app. I Followed all necessary prerequisites.

So I made a simple activity to test it out.

```
public class SpaineMapActivity extends Activity {
    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    private GoogleMap map;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }
}
```

and with xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It works fine. No problem. But when I try to integrate it to my other app with all libs loaded of course. But even just at the setContentView() part, I already get the error. Both layout are the same.

```
public class act_map extends FragmentActivity {
    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    private GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lyt_map);


        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error

```
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:269)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:257)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at dev.foogle.act_map.onCreate(act_map.java:21)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4978)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
02-21 19:19:25.650: E/AndroidRuntime(23097):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you can't use same map api key for two different apps.

Comment: Your first one extends "Activity" and second one extends "FragmentActivity": Two differ each other. Please change your second one so that it extends "Activity" and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> with all libs loaded of course

Your error suggests that the Play Services library project's JAR was not found in your project. Make sure that you have attached the Play Services library project to your new app (e.g., via Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse).

Comment: My demo project did not require it and is still works.

And this project where I am planning to integrate the map, even though I tried to mannual add the google-play-services.jar, still the same error...

I can run the map with this code:
//
SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
//

But I can't assign it to a GoogleMap variable. 

fragment.getMap() returns a null

Comment: @SpaineCarinan: "My demo project did not require it and is still works" -- then you are not using Maps V2, as Maps V2 requires the Play Services library project. "And this project where I am planning to integrate the map, even though I tried to mannual add the google-play-services.jar, still the same error" -- do not "mannual add" the JAR. Add the library project. Read these two Web pages: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start and http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: CommonsWare, great thanks! Adding lib project and removing all other jars (google-play-services & support-v4) solved the problem!